# MS Visual Studio 2012 Web deploy doesn't show new site

Tags: visual-studio-2012

So I am trying to use Web Deploy for the first time. 
Within Visual Studio everything seems to be fine, it says that it was deployed successfully. 
Problem is: the site has not gotten the new site. I don't see my changes. 
I should point out that I don't upload the web.config from my local machine to my server.

Any idea what could be the cause?

Thanks

Comment: Any possibility of a caching issue here?  Can you verify if the files on the server were modified?

Comment: The dates on the server seem to show the new time.

Comment: And the files on the server show the right content?  Sounds like maybe your browser is caching the pages...

Comment: I don't know how to test what the files on the server actually show.
They should as the date is the new date.

Comment: In the end, I deleted the existing site from the server and started a new one from Web Deploy and it updates beautifully every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in the current "real world debugging system" that Microsoft use. If possible, you should delete all the already published content, and republish. This should resolve the issue temporarily. I'm assured that Microsoft are working on a fix, though I can't find the thread I was posting on before...

I actually had the problem using the Windows Phone SDK, but I'm almost certain that this is a very similar issue, probably the same root cause. Give it a shot if possible, if it's a live site maybe you can arrange a test URL to work with?

Josh

Comment: Once I delete the first time will the publish work every time after that?

Comment: you had an issue with the Phone SDK, and you think it's the same issue as in Web Deployment?

Comment: After deleting the project from the Windows phone OSs (both virtualised and physical device), mine updated to show the changes. Each time after I first experienced this issue I've had to do it. @Jimmy I did also see similar behavior in a web app I was trying out, although that may have just been me being a pleb. Note I don't know for sure that this is a valid workaround, as with Jimmy's suspicion, it could be a completely different issue, but it's worth trying on a non-production system.